# Dope sheet: why some keyframes are connected and some aren't?

Tags: keyframes, dopesheet

I setup some keyframes in Dope Sheet:

[image]

I'm not sure if I understand why some keyframes are connected (yellow bar between them) and some are not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This "bar" indicates that there is no change between the connected keyframes for the attribute.

For example, you keyframed *X Scale* at frame 1 and again at frame 20 but the *X Scale* is the same. This is shown by the connection. At frame 40 you scaled the object down and added a keyframe. Then there is no connection between frames 20 and 40 because Blender will interpolate the scale between these frames. That is, the object starts to shrink slowly from frame 20 to 40.